Encountered error: @parcel/optimizer-swc: 'const' declarations must be initialized (during build process)
I encountered an error during the build process with Parcel, specifically from the @parcel/optimizer-swc module, stating that 'const' declarations must be initialized. However, this error doesn't arise during npm start. What could be the reason?This is the link to the codebase
I tried solving this using chatGpt, official docs but couldn't find the answer.

Does the error contain a line number? Please look into where exactly the error is coming from.

This is the error I'm getting :-
@parcel/optimizer-swc: 'const' declarations must be initialized
19937 |


19938 |
| ^
19939 | const $4c8cda5d2c6d1d8b$var$Grocery = /#PURE/ (0, $acw62.lazy)(()=>(parcelRequire("7RwBr")));
19940 |

